# Login loop when I try Ubuntu

Tags: ati, login, live-usb

I want to install ubuntu 14.04 on my acer 7741ZG but I detected some problems before installation thanks the liveUSB.

When I try Ubuntu, the login screen appears, very strange for a liveUSB,
I put 'ubuntu' in username but when I valid, a black screen appears and after that, it goes back to the login screen directly.

I tested the liveUSB on other computer and it works fine. So I suppose that is a problem of video card (ATI radeon 5470).
I also tried to modify permissions of .Xauthority, reinstall compiz, lightdm ...
etc but still the same problem ...

To be sure, I tried an older version of Ubuntu (12.10) on this laptop and the liveUSB works fine: Maybe there are some incompatibilities with the display manager of the 14.10 version

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can do is try a little debugging, although i don't think that the video card is the problem since ubuntu can technically run on an onboard graphics card but nonetheless try switching them out. Next thing is that what you are describing is a lack of power so try to put it in a powered hub or at least a USB port on the back.

Comment: I tried solutions you proposed but it still the same problem, It's very strnage because I used Ubuntu 1 year ago and I had no problems. I formatted my hard drive and now I can't reinstall ubuntu ....

Comment: Have you tried just pressing enter at the log in screen or using su as the username and password as blank?

Answer (score 0):

I tried live debian on my computer (with GNOME) and I had also this kind of problem, a screen with this message:
"A problem has occured and the system and can't recover ...".

I guess it is a hardware problem ...
But it's very strange because I have already installed a linux OS without problems.

I tested W10 but went back to W7. Is there a consequence of this change?